# Assetic generates several CSS files that have been deleted

Tags: css, caching, symfony, assetic

I'm having trouble with Assetic in Symfony2. It looks like it manages his own cache, because it's generating every CSS file that historically have been in my project, despite I've deleted many of them (and cleared both Symfony's caches). For example, I have 8 CSS files in the whole project, but it loads like 12, and when I do assetic:dump it generates 91 different files. With JS works fine.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assetic looks for files in the /web/bundles/ directory, so you need to clear it also.

Alternatively use symlink. `assets:install web --symlink`

Comment: I've managed to solve it. Don't know why, but something was generating ~cssname.css files in my CSS directory and Nautilus was not showing them because they were hidden files. If someone have the same issue just press CTRL + H to view those hidden files. Thanks anyway Inori!